# How can I configure and use a time_interval from eg Friday 20:00 to Monday 07:00?

Tags: configuration, notifications, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to disable certain Prometheus alerts between Friday and Monday. We already configured our reciever and routes like the following:

```
routes:
- receiver: 'msteams'
  matchers:
    - alertname =~ "Example-.+"
  mute_time_intervals:
    - weekend
```

Now I'm stuck at defining the time interval `weekend`

We made sure that the alert itself works as expected.

I tried refering to the documentiation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#time_interval) but I would like to see a full example with a `time_interval`section which I can refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a weekend time interval as:

```
time_intervals:
  - name: my_weekends
    time_intervals:
      - weekdays: ['friday']
        times:
          - start_time: 20:00
            end_time: 24:00
      - weekdays: ['saturday:sunday']
      - weekdays: ['moonday']
        times:
          - start_time: 0:00
            end_time: 7:00
```